# Reading repeated fields in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am pretty new to ASP.NET. I have an application where user's education need to be accepted. The education set of input fields need to be repeated if the user prefers to enter details of another education degree. What is the best way to do this? I am using Web forms.

I was thinking of creating a user control for education fields and generating it dynamically. Will that work? I am not sure how to read that though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).